# Wie vermeidet man die Wiederholung eines Präfixes?

Tags: prefix, compound

Man kann z. B. schreiben

> Die heutige Informations- und Wissensgesellschaft ...

um die Wiederholung eines Suffixes (hier "Gesellschaft") zu vermeiden. Aber wie macht man dasselbe, wenn es sich um ein Präfix handelt? Zum Beispiel:

> Die Leistungen der Spitzenfußballspieler und der Spitzenschwimmer ...

Wie kann man "Spitzen" nur einmal schreiben? Ist das überhaupt möglich? Mein Versuch:

> Die Leistungen der Spitzen-Fußballspieler und -Schwimmer ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prinzipiell genau so wie beim Suffix, nur dass eben nicht das Suffix, sondern das Prefix abgekoppelt wird.

> Die Leistungen der Spitzenfußballspieler und -schwimmer...

Comment: Von manchen wird das aber als schlechter Schreibstil angesehen; bei kurzen Wörtern ist es manchmal besser, alles jeweils auszuschreiben.

Comment: @BarthZalewski Im Beispiel würde es sich auch lohnen auszuschreiben, falls man davon ausgehen könnte, dass es auch als "Spitzenfußballschwimmer" interpretiert werden könnte.

Comment: Ja, das wollte ich auch schreiben, hab's dann aber doch noch gelassen. Bin derselben Meinung.

Comment: Dafür hat man dann die Bindestriche.

Comment: Merke, dass dann der Artikel entfällt und beide Wörter denselben Numerus haben müssen.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Nein, hat man nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Doch, hat man schon.

Comment: Kann man auch vorne UND hinten etwas abkoppeln?

Comment: @MaxRied Also du solltest es dir 10x überlegen, bevor du sowas schreibst: "Spitzenfußballspieler- und -schwimmergesellschaft" – Ich wage zu behaupten. Nein, man kann's nicht.